# nRF24L01 6TXA_1RXA network + 6TXB_1RXB network with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

[image: nRF24L01 6TXA_1RXA network + 6TXB_1RXB network with arduino]

How to build nRF24L01 network shown above with arduino ?
SPI pins are shared between RXA,RXB and separate pins for both CE, CSN, IRQ.

Which nRF24L01 library supports my requirements ?

Comment: You can share the SPI (MISO, MOSI and SCK) pins but need separate pins for IRQ, CE, CSN.

Comment: @Kwasmich This is all the information that the OP requires, but please write an answer too.

Comment: @MichaelT My comment was meant to be an obvious generality to let zastereo improve on his/her question. I don't think the raw pin connection is what was asked about. So I hope for more details on the actual problem.

Comment: @Kwasmich Off-course I need separate pins for IRQ, CE, CSN

Comment: Answer below is definitely correct, but just to be sure: are you aware you probably don’t actually NEED two masters? The 6 peers limitation of the nRF24 doesn’t apply unless you are using databurst protocol

Answer (score 3):

You can use the RF24 library that you can install right away from the Arduino IDE. It provides you all you need. Just use two instances of `RF24` with different CSN and CE pins assigned to get started.

```
RF24 radioA(7, 8); // CE, CSN
RF24 radioB(5, 6); // CE, CSN
```

Use the simple ping sketch as a starting point and add a second radio to it.